# Update date field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, crud

I have the below document in a collection named "review". I want to update the expiry date in the past. Minus 1 day

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62bd783086e0ee2176477b93"),
    "expiry" : ISODate("2022-09-28T10:17:20.455Z"),
    "rating" : 5,
    "category" : "Orange Pumpkin Namkeen",
    "merchantId" : "220606131134369EZ0045009",
    "customerName" : "The Man with the Yellow Hat",
    "customerId" : "220606142940700EZ0043018",
    "status" : "SUBMITTED",
    "createdTime" : ISODate("2022-06-30T10:17:20.456Z"),
    "modifiedTime" : ISODate("2022-06-30T10:20:51.955Z"),
    "modifiedBy" : "ezestore"
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.test.insert({"Time" : new ISODate("2012-01-10") });


db.test.update({ criteria }, { newObj }, upsert, multi);
For example, to update all objects, consider

db.test.update( {}, { $set : { "time" : new ISODate("2012-01-11T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).